# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to deploy or upload a Java Application in Elastic Beanstalk.

1. Is Elastic Beanstalk a Free Tier eligible service?
2. If yes, how long it will be?? Like EC2 750 hrs/ Month
3. Read the pricing paragraph in Elastic Beanstalk dashboard. But it seems like Elastic Beanstalk internally using EC2 instance. I am confused here.

As of now my application does not have any database connection, calling API and getting the data instead.

If I deploy the application in Elastic Beanstalk, as a Free Tier user (as of now) anything will be charged for up and running the Elastic Beanstalk service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct - Elastic Beanstalk uses Amazon EC2 instances, Load Balancers and Amazon RDS databases.

From [AWS Elastic Beanstalk Pricing - Amazon Web Services (AWS)](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/pricing/):

> There is no additional charge for AWS Elastic Beanstalk. You pay for AWS resources (e.g. EC2 instances or S3 buckets) you create to store and run your application. You only pay for what you use, as you use it; there are no minimum fees and no upfront commitments.

Therefore, if the Amazon EC2 instance(s) used by Elastic Beanstalk meet the requirements of the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) (eg using T2 or T3 micro instances), then they would fall under the Free Tier.

The free tier includes (in the first 12 months of your account):

- 750 hours per month of Linux, RHEL, or SLES t2.micro or t3.micro instance dependent on region
- 750 hours per month of Windows t2.micro or t3.micro instance dependent on region

Comment: When testing EB with the 'getting-started-app' setup process (docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/…), if you choose ".NET on Windows Server" as the platform for your test app, it auto-selects a t3.medium instance to be created. I understand that t3.medium is not covered by the Free Tier. You *can* change the configuration settings in the setup process to choose t2.micro, which does fall under Free Tier, but the default configuration for Windows Server is t3.medium - whether this will affect the performance of your 'getting-started-app' is another question.

Comment: @John My doubt is, EC2(t2.micro) and load balance(t2.micro) both are are t2.micro instances. Will I get 750 hours per month combining both or 750 hours each?

Comment: @ImranAhmad Load Balancers are _not_ t2.micro, they are a separate service from Amazon EC2. Both Amazon EC2 and Load Balancers have 750 hours per month in the Free Tier. See conditions at: https://aws.amazon.com/free/

Comment: Why does https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/pricing/ mention S3? I understand EC2 is used to host the website, and RDS for database. What is use case of S3?

Comment: @variable See: [Using Elastic Beanstalk with Amazon S3 - AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.S3.html)

Comment: Ok I had read that Elastic beanstalk makes use of EC2, so I assumed that via EC2 (run the website) it will make use of Elastic Block storage to store the website files. Whereas you are saying that Elastic beanstalk uses EC2 (run the website) and S3 for the storage of the website files. Have I understood this correctly?